# requestAnimationFrame : different behavior between retina display and secondary monitor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requestanimationframe

I'm building a React App, and I'm using requestAnimationFrame to apply special CSS effect over some elements controlled by a parallax lib (Plx).

My effect should be applied dynamically on scroll event, but the eventListener was not running smoothly. When I implemented RAF, the animation run great on my second monitor, but terribly on my macbook display (lagging effect).

Same browser, same tab, no refresh.

here's how I start the loop:

```
setTimeout(function () {

    var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame ||    
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

    var $window = $(window);

    var lastScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

    if (raf) {
        loop();
    }

    function loop() {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (TextGalaxy.resetScrollSpeed) {
            return false;
        }

        if (lastScrollTop === scrollTop) {
            raf(loop);
            return false;
        } else {
            lastScrollTop = scrollTop;

            // fire scroll function if scrolls vertically
            TextGalaxy.updateScreenView();
            raf(loop);
        }
    }
}, 20);
```

Has anyone have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Comment: What does that `updateScreenView()` ? Is it modifying DOM ?

Comment: @c-smile yes updateScreenView() tracks the position of a div, and update the position of another div.